# GROUP BY in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to write a GROUP BY query in elastic search using version 5.2

I want to query the data and limit that down to those which have a particular 'tag'. In the case below. I want to select items which contain the word "FIY" in the title or content fields and then narrow that down so as to only search those documents which have the tags "FIY" and "Competition"

The query part is fine but I am struggling to limit it to the given tag.

So far I have got, but I am getting the error.

"reason": "[bool] query does not support [terms]",

```
GET advice-articles/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "FIY",
        "fields": ["title", "content"]
      }
    }
  ], "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "terms": {
        "tags.tagName": [
           "competition"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
 }
}
```

an example index is

```
"_index": "advice-articles",
    "_type": "article",
    "_id": "1460",
    "_score": 4.3167734,
    "_source": {
      "id": "1460",
      "title": "Your top FIY tips",
      "content": "Fix It Yourself in April 2012.",
      "tags": [
        {
          "tagName": "Fix it yourself"
        },
        {
          "tagName": "customer tips"
        },
        {
          "tagName": "competition"
        }
      ]
```

the mappings I have are as follows

```
{
"advice-articles": {
"mappings": {
  "article": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "tagName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

}

Comment: I think when you write "bool" it has to be followed either by "must", "should", "filter", or "must_not". See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) built using one or more boolean clauses, each clause with a typed occurrence. The occurrence types are:
`must`, `must_not`, `filter`, `should`

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "FIY",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "tags.tagName": [
                  "competition"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how you can use a must clause for your query requirements.

Comment: if I use the above its does not return any results, using should returns results not but not the correct documents

Comment: @simon1230756 missed the nested part for tags, updated the query. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the **filter** you dont need to put bool.

```
POST newindex/test/1460333
{
  "title": "Your top FIY tips",
  "content": "Fix It Yourself in April 2012.",
  "tags": [
    {
      "tagName": "Fix it yourself"
    },
    {
      "tagName": "customer tips"
    },
    {
      "tagName": "shoud not return"
    }
  ]
}

POST newindex/test/1460
{
  "title": "Your top FIY tips",
  "content": "Fix It Yourself in April 2012.",
  "tags": [
    {
      "tagName": "Fix it yourself"
    },
    {
      "tagName": "customer tips"
    },
    {
      "tagName": "competition"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query:

```
GET newindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "FIY",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "tags.tagName": [
            "competition"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result :

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "newindex",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1460",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Your top FIY tips",
          "content": "Fix It Yourself in April 2012.",
          "tags": [
            {
              "tagName": "Fix it yourself"
            },
            {
              "tagName": "customer tips"
            },
            {
              "tagName": "competition"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: if I use the above its does not return any results, using should returns results not but not the correct documents

Comment: @simon1230756 have a look (above) with full example, which works correctly using elasticsearch 5.2

Comment: thanks, still didnt work for me but noticed my mapping was set as nested, all good now :-)